# Run a Function Upon Exiting a Neovim Terminal

Tags: lua, neovim

By using the following code...

```lua
vim.fn.termopen("foo")
```

I can open a terminal with a certain command. What I want to do is run a Lua function from a plugin upon exiting the terminal.

Pseudo Code:

```
vim.fn.termopen("foo", run "lua require('my-plugin').someFunction()" upon exiting)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research, I found that there are two autocommands I can use that suit my needs

```
au TermClose * lua require('my-plugin').someFunction()

or

au TermLeave * lua require('my-plugin').someFunction()
```

The first one works better for me because I only want to run my function once the terminal is killed/closed. The second one is for if you want to run a function once the user switches from the terminal to something else.

Answer (score 0):

`vim.fn.termopen({cmd} [, {opts}])` includes an `on_exit` opts value which is a callback. This will ensure the callback is explicitly paired to *this* terminal and not all terminals exiting.

```lua
vim.fn.termopen("foo", {
    on_exit = function(job_id, code, event)
        require("my-plugin").someFunction()
    end
})
```

If you do want to wrap all terminal exits, your autocommand solution is the best option.